# Comma: "No test source roots in the project: is it properly configured?"

Tags: raku, commaide

Comma 2020.07 (community edition) has changed the test configuration, and now you can test different things: module, project and so on. However, I can't simply get it to run the usual tests. When I use "All in project" testing, I get this error:

```
No test source roots in the project: is it properly configured?
```

I have no idea where to set the source roots, or how to configure it properly. Tests are in the usual place, `t/`.

Comment: [A google for "test source roots"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22test+source+roots%22) makes it clear this is a general IntelliJ thing. The first SO I looked at talks about starting with **Project Structure** (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`S`) and then arriving at some screen where you add "test source roots in this root". Whatever that means. If that doesn't help, maybe [a google for "source roots"+IntelliJ](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22source+roots%22+IntelliJ) will? Tbh I've literally no IDEA but thought any comment was better than NO idea at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a new project is created or imported, the `lib` directory should get marked as a source root (where modules live) and the `t` directory as a test root (where the tests live). Previously, Comma paid no attention to these markings and just hard-coded looking in the `t` directory for tests, but ongoing work is aiming to support a wider range of project structures, and thus as of a recent release the concept of test root started to matter.

Somehow, you've ended up with a project where the `t` folder is not marked as a test root. I'm not sure how that happened, but there are ways to try to fix this situation.

One is to re-import the project from source, which should set it up correctly, but will lose run configurations.

An alternative is to open the `.iml` file in the root directory of the project. In a correctly configured project there will be an entry like this:

```
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/lib" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/t" isTestSource="true" />
    </content>
```

Yours is probably missing the entry for the `t` directory with `isTestSource` set to `true`.

Future Comma versions will provide a way on the UI to do this, so that one can set up multiple test roots if needed (`t` and `xt` for example).

Comment: There's no such thing, I'm afraid. It might be taking the template from an older configuration file, or something, because I keep getting it for new modules. Where would the source for that be so that I don't have to change it by hand for every new project?

Comment: The UI support for this has been in place for quite a while now; right-click on the directory in the file tree, `Mark Directory As` > `Test Sources Root`.